# Automatic php script to know how many view have your page with Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I want to know the number of view of my web page using a script php that query Google Analytic.
I know that there is the Google API, but there is a bad documentation of it. 
You know how do that?

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for a simple script that just saves the number of a page view in the database and later you could get the value , or you want to get the number of page view calculated with the google Analytic api ? in that case , you're talking about building a Rest Api (Interact with the google server) and you should read about the google APi .